# Calculating Total at multiple timestamps from one table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table which has around 5000 records with 4 types of ordes at multiple timestamps, i have been tryint to calculate the **count of orders at multiple timestamps like 00 to 04hrs, 04hrs to 24hrs**. All i can acheive the result for either of 1 timestamp.
appriciate your help :)

```
SELECT
    DECODE(order_type,1,'Multi Sim',2,'Single Sim',3,'Sim Replacement',7,'Data SIM with Router') AS order_type,
    COUNT(order_type) AS total0hrs_4hrs,
    COUNT(order_type) AS total4hrs_24hrs,
    COUNT(order_type) AS grand_total
FROM
    sids
WHERE
    order_time >= to_timestamp('2020-09-01 00:00:00.0000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF4')
    AND order_time <= to_timestamp('2020-09-01 03:59:59.9999','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF4')
    AND order_type IN (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        7
    )
GROUP BY
    order_type
HAVING
    COUNT(order_type) > 0
ORDER BY
    1;
```

[image: This is the result, which i can produce, need to produce the result for 2 timestamps]

Comment: Huh?  Please edit the question and show the definition of the SIDS table, and sample data rows.

Comment: why are you counting order_type and naming it like it is a timestamp. it looks wrong. does order_time has time fraction?

Comment: I have added the sample records of the table to which i am refereing to.

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu, DB contains around 5k records on 4 types of orders, thats the reason i am calculating the Total count on Order_type, this column naming is the basic requirment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression within your aggregation functions:

```sql
SELECT DECODE(
         order_type,
         1, 'Multi Sim',
         2, 'Single Sim',
         3, 'Sim Replacement',
         7, 'Data SIM with Router'
       ) AS order_type,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN order_time - TRUNC( order_time ) < INTERVAL '4' HOUR
         THEN 1
         ELSE NULL
         END
       ) AS total0hrs_4hrs,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN order_time - TRUNC( order_time ) < INTERVAL '4' HOUR
         THEN NULL
         ELSE 1
         END
       ) AS total4hrs_24hrs,
       COUNT(order_type) AS grand_total
FROM   sids
WHERE  order_time >= TIMESTAMP '2020-09-01 00:00:00.0000'
AND    order_time <  TIMESTAMP '2020-09-02 00:00:00.0000'
AND    order_type IN ( 1, 2, 3, 7 )
GROUP BY
       order_type
ORDER BY
       1;
```

Comment: Did little modification & got the result :) Thanks @MT0